# array data is repeating in table view in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

these are some variable , which data I want to show in table view or collection view.

```
   let inr = ["200.0", "1200.0", "500.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "3000.0", "5000.0", "1000.0", "100000.0", "100000.0"]
let reqtime = ["2018-04-11 13:54:46", "2018-04-09 16:31:42", "2018-04-09 12:26:32", "2018-04-09 12:19:40", "2018-04-09 12:19:35", "2018-04-09 12:19:23", "2018-04-09 12:09:05", "2018-04-09 12:08:25", "2018-04-09 11:38:15", "2018-04-09 11:07:59", "2018-04-09 11:03:58", "2018-04-09 10:54:55", "2018-04-09 10:45:47"]
let status = ["Request Approve", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Approve", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Pending", "Request Approve"]
```

This is my table view Delegate Function Code:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //print("inrvalue sec\(self.inrValues.count)")
    return inr.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    //print("section p\(self.requestTimeValue[section])")
    return reqtime[section]
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DepositHistoryTableViewCell


    let inrval = Double(inr[indexPath.section])
    cell.lblINR.text = String(inrval)

    cell.lblStatus.text = status[indexPath.section]


    return cell
}
```

Data shown like this image:
[table view data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frBhg.png)

Question 1. want to show data like this...

```
Section: reqtime(row[0]) 
inr(row[0])
status(row[0]),
Section: reqtime(row[1])
inr(row[1]) 
status(row[1])
Section: reqtime(row[2])
inr(row[2])
status(row[2])
```

and so on.

question 2: is there any other way to show this data in better way like this:[any other way to data like this in swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4cPh.png)

after change my code, data is showing like this in image below:[this is how data shown after numberofRowinSection return 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B03Dz.png)

Comment: Note that `inr`, `status` and `reqtime` are synch'ed. They should be in a big one array (with custom objects), not separated like this. For the second question: Yes, you can, you just have to code a custom cell that mimic it, and adapt your datasource to it.

Comment: Check your `numberOfRowsInSection`. Print out `section`. I'm pretty sure it returns 1,2,3,4... etc. Can't test right now. Return 1 instead of `section`.

Comment: no, its returning only first value of inr and status @Akaino

Comment: @Larme could you explain this with code, it may be helpful, thanks

Comment: @Larme actually I'm fetching this data from api , this explanation is just demo to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here you have same no of items in `inr`, `reqtime` and `status` so for each `inr` item you will only have a single `reqtime` and `single` status:

**Update your `numberOfRowsInSection` as:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

**Note:** Currently you are returning `reqtime[section]` **(String)** in this method which is also not right as this function can only have a `Int` return value.

[image]

**Update UITableView's delegate and datasource methods as:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return inr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return reqtime[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Here you have same no of items in inr, reqtime and status so for each inr item you will only have a single reqtime and single status
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DepositHistoryTableViewCell

    let inrval = Double(inr[indexPath.section])
    cell.lblINR.text = String(format: "%.2f",inrval)
    cell.lblStatus.text = status[indexPath.section]

    return cell
}
```

**Update:** 
// If you wish to show data like a horizontal table

```
let inr = ["200.0", "1200.0", "500.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "2000.0", "3000.0", "5000.0", "1000.0", "100000.0", "100000.0"]
let reqtime = ["2018-04-11 13:54:46", "2018-04-09 16:31:42", "2018-04-09 12:26:32", "2018-04-09 12:19:40", "2018-04-09 12:19:35", "2018-04-09 12:19:23", "2018-04-09 12:09:05", "2018-04-09 12:08:25", "2018-04-09 11:38:15", "2018-04-09 11:07:59", "2018-04-09 11:03:58", "2018-04-09 10:54:55", "2018-04-09 10:45:47"]
let status = ["Approve", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Approve", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Approve"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return inr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DepositHistoryTableViewCell

    cell.lblRequestTime.text = reqtime[indexPath.row]
    let inrval = Double(inr[indexPath.row])
    cell.lblINR.text = String(format: "%.2f",inrval!)
    cell.lblStatus.text = status[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: He's returning `string` for the title only. `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `int` as it should.

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection`, Returning the value as `return reqtime[section]` which is a String value as  `reqtime` is an String array

Comment: it doesn't work , I have changed my code and replaced return reqtime[section] with return 1@AnkitJayaswal

Comment: @BaljinderKumar, I am getting the data as attached screenshot. Haven't you getting like this?

Comment: No, @AnkitJayaswal

Comment: check my 2nd question, data should be like this, 1-1-1,2-2-2,3-3-3(request time-inr-status).

Comment: Section: reqtime(row[0])  , inr(row[0]) , status(row[0]), in next , Section: reqtime(row[1])  , inr(row[1]) , status(row[1]), and next Section: reqtime(row[2])  , inr(row[2]) , status(row[2]), and so on..

Comment: got it, thanks for reply and Can you help to solve e my Question 2 ?

Comment: Check if it helps

Comment: I also want to show button in each row  to redirect for add reference of selected entry

Comment: You can add a button or even you can do the action on clicking of cell too.

Comment: @Akaino, No problem :)